# How to make a payout with PayPal Payouts PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am learning php and I would like to make a payment with Paypal. I tried to run the code example (https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-PHP-SDK), but I couldn't get it to work. If someone could help me, I would be very grateful. This is my code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\SandboxEnvironment;

// Creating an environment
$clientId = "******************";
$clientSecret = "***************";
$environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
$client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);





use PaypalPayoutsSDK\Payouts\PayoutsPostRequest;
$request = new PayoutsPostRequest();

$body= json_decode(
            '{
                "sender_batch_header":
                {
                  "email_subject": "SDK payouts test txn"
                },
                "items": [
                {
                  "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                  "receiver": "payouts2342@paypal.com",
                  "note": "Your 1$ payout",
                  "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12",
                  "amount":
                  {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "value": "1.00"
                  }
                }]
              }',             
            true);
            
$request->body = $body;
$client = PayPalClient::client();




$response = $client->execute($request);
echo 'resuelto<br>';
print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
print "Status: {$response->result->batch_header->batch_status}\n";
print "Batch ID: {$response->result->batch_header->payout_batch_id}\n";
print "Links:\n";
foreach($response->result->links as $link)
 {
   print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
 }
echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
```

and this is the message when I run it:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException:
> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication
> failed"} in
> /var/www/html/paypal/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php:215

> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/paypal/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(100):
> PayPalHttp\HttpClient->parseResponse() #1
> /var/www/html/paypal/vendor/paypal/paypal-payouts-sdk/lib/PaypalPayoutsSDK/Core/AuthorizationInjector.php(37):
> PayPalHttp\HttpClient->execute() #2
> /var/www/html/paypal/vendor/paypal/paypal-payouts-sdk/lib/PaypalPayoutsSDK/Core/AuthorizationInjector.php(29):
> PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\AuthorizationInjector->fetchAccessToken() #3
> /var/www/html/paypal/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(64):
> PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\AuthorizationInjector->inject() #4
> /var/www/html/paypal/index.php(48): PayPalHttp\HttpClient->execute()
> #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/paypal/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php
> on line 215

Comment: What's your question about this? Have you read the error message? If yes: what have you tried to resolve the error?

Comment: Check your code, you defined a $client on line #10, and then redefined on line #41

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not entered the PayPal Client Id and Secret.
First you have to register to PayPal Developer (or access with your PayPal account if you already have one): https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

Then create an application and grant Payout permissions.

Then in your application you'll find Client Id and Secret codes.

Finally you only need to copy and paste them into your PHP code, in these two lines:

```
$clientId = "******************";
$clientSecret = "***************";
```

For example:

```
$clientId = "123456";
$clientSecret = "aAbBcC";
```